# Making the 'draw' condition in Tic Tac Toe JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, tic-tac-toe

Having trouble programming the 'Draw' condition in my Tic Tac Toe game on JavaScript. I put in my win conditions as function(s) 'checkWin1-7', I'm struggling to see how to put in a 'draw'condition. Would I go about using an else if statement? When I tried using it, the code stopped working. I'd appreciate some help in this regard.

```js
let state;

const gameState = {
  players: ['x', 'o'],
  board: [
    null, null, null,
    null, null, null,
    null, null, null
  ]
}

const gameArea = document.getElementById('gameBoard');

let playerXTurn = true;

function checkWin1(playerIcon) {
  let gameWon = true; //diagonal L to R
  for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
    if(gameState.board[i*4]!=playerIcon){
      gameWon = false;
      break;
    }
  } return gameWon
}

function checkWin2(playerIcon){
  gameWon = true; //diagonal R to L
  for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
    if(gameState.board[(i*2)+2]!=playerIcon){
      gameWon = false;
      break;
    }
  } return gameWon
}

function checkWin3(playerIcon){
  gameWon = true; //0 3 6 down
  for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
    if(gameState.board[(i*3)]!=playerIcon){
      gameWon = false;
      break;
    }
  } return gameWon
}

function checkWin4(playerIcon){
  gameWon = true; //0 1 2 across
    for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
      if(gameState.board[i]!=playerIcon){
        gameWon = false;
        break;
      }
    } return gameWon
}

function checkWin5(playerIcon){
  gameWon = true; //3 4 5 across
    for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
      if(gameState.board[(i+2)+1]!=playerIcon){
        gameWon = false;
        break;
      }
    } return gameWon
}

function checkWin6(playerIcon){
  gameWon = true; //6 7 8 across
    for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
      if(gameState.board[(i+5)+1]!=playerIcon){
        gameWon = false;
        break;
      }
    } return gameWon
}

function checkWin7(playerIcon){
  gameWon = true; //1 4 7 down
    for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
      if(gameState.board[(i*3)+1]!=playerIcon){
        gameWon = false;
        break;
      }
    } return gameWon
}

function checkWin8(playerIcon){
  gameWon = true; //2 5 8 down
    for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
      if(gameState.board[(i*2)+2+i]!=playerIcon){
        gameWon = false;
        break;
      }
    } return gameWon
}



function onBoardClick(event){
const cellClass = event.target.classList;
  if(cellClass.contains('X_BoardPiece')||cellClass.contains('O_BoardPiece')){
    return;
  } 

  let cellId = event.target.id.substring(5);
 

  if (playerXTurn) {
    event.target.classList.add('X_BoardPiece')
  
    console.log(event.target.id.substring(5))
  
    gameState.board[cellId-1] = 'x'
    const isWinner = checkWin1('x') || checkWin2('x') || checkWin3('x') || checkWin4('x') || checkWin5('x') || checkWin6('x') || checkWin7('x') || checkWin8('x')
    if (isWinner) {
      alert ("player x is the winner")
    }
 
  }
  else {
    event.target.classList.add('O_BoardPiece')
    console.log(event.target.id.substring(5))
    gameState.board[cellId-1] = 'o'
    const isWinner = checkWin1('o') || checkWin2('o') || checkWin3('o') || checkWin4('o') || checkWin5('o') || checkWin6('o') || checkWin7('o') || checkWin8('o')
    if (isWinner) {
      alert ("player o is the winner")
    }
  }

  console.log(gameState.board)
  playerXTurn = !playerXTurn
}

gameArea.addEventListener('click', onBoardClick);
```

Comment: html code is missing.

Comment: Two observations: you only need 1 function for checking a winning move (you can for instance store a bidimensional array with all 8 winning positions). Regarding the draw: it's only a draw when the board is full and nobody won (even though everybody that plays tic-tac-toe knows when a game will end in a draw).

Comment: A break inside the if statement, could be the problem. Break is for While or switch loops.

Answer (score 0):

A draw is when the board is full. With your data structure this means there is no more `null` in the `board` array.

To implement it, extend this code:

```
if (isWinner) {
  alert ("player x is the winner")
}
```

to

```
if (isWinner) {
  alert ("player x is the winner")
} else if (!gameState.board.includes(null)) {
  alert('Draw!!');
}
```

#### Other remarks

The `check*` functions have too much code repetition. They all look alike except for the cells they check. You could benefit from this function:

```
function checkWin(playerIcon) {
  const winners = [
    [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]
  ];
  return winners.some(winner =>
    winner.every(cell => gameState.board[cell] === playerIcon)
  );
}
```

Using `alert` has many disadvantages: it blocks the update of the page, so that the last move is not displayed. It is better to provide a element in your HTML where you display messages. This is non-blocking.

Also, once the game is over, no other code should execute, and the clicking a cell should not do anything.